# Get number of columns in Excel using Oracle

Tags: excel, oracle

is a possibility to get number of columns in Excel document using Oracle? I can't find even any similar question to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [plsql-utils](https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils) library, the ooxml_utils_pkg package, to open an Excel file and interrogate the contents. You have to know a bit about the file, like how it's laid out to determine what cells to look at to see if they're populated.